# PHP Update form using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP, I need some help here. I have created a form called **Home.php** which accepts ID,name & file upload as inputs and it adds into mysql. Its adding successfully. I want to perform update operation so that if a user wants to update any of the fields. So what I want is it has to update these 3 fields in db. **But I'm getting a following error in Process.php**.

**Error : Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement**

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE info SET id=?, name=?, upload=? WHERE id=?";
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)))
{
  die("Unable to prepare statement");
}
else
{
  $stmt->bind_param("iss", $id, $name, $upload);    
  if($stmt->execute())
  {
    echo "Successfully updated";
  }
  else
  {
    die("Update failed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 4 parameters needed for

```
$sql = "UPDATE info SET id=?, name=?, upload=? WHERE id=?";
```

Even if id should be the same, since you didn't give it name, you have to add it 2 times in your binding

```
$stmt->bind_param("issi", $id, $name, $upload, $id);
```

should work

You should check about adding named params in statements to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

this error is due to

```
 $sql = "UPDATE info SET id=?, name=?, upload=? WHERE id=?";
```

here in this query have bind 4 parameter

but in you bind only 3 param

```
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $id, $name, $upload);
```

here it should be

```
$stmt->bind_param("issi", $id, $name, $upload,$id);
```

AS per our discussion your final query would be

```
$sql = "UPDATE info name=?, upload=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt->bind_param("ssi",  $name, $upload,$id);
```

Comment: I tried this and now the error gone, but file is uploading to the DOC folder. Simply it is showing message that successfully updated but its not updating.

Comment: @mak error gone it means this ans working fine for you. Now check you update query . Try to print your query and check what is the problem

Comment: How to do that using var_dump?

Comment: Yeah I did that.                                                                              Successfully updated
object(mysqli_stmt)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => int 1
  public 'insert_id' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 0
  public 'param_count' => int 4
  public 'field_count' => int 0
  public 'errno' => int 0
  public 'error' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'error_list' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'sqlstate' => string '00000' (length=5)
  public 'id' => int 1

File is uploaded successfully...

Comment: I'm waiting for your reply.

Comment: I got this error. Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::errorInfo()

Comment: check updade query work or not see and check your database. I think this query working

Comment: Now its working. I removed id field from UPDATE query & bind_param function. Thanks.

Comment: @MAK i also need your support